# How to manually set exposure on a Facetime HD camera in Python opencv 3.2.0 OSX El Capitan

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, osx-elcapitan, opencv3.0

I am trying to figure out how to manually set the exposure for my Facetime HD camera in the `opencv` program I am writing in Python. I am using `opencv` version 3.2.0, python 2.7, and running on OSX El Capitan.

I am writing a program which will take a photograph from the webcam every n seconds and write it to the disk. From what I have seen in the documentation, I would want to use this method to set the exposure on my camera.

`cv2.VideoCapture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE, value) → retval`

After some tinkering and looking around online, I found I was able to access that camera property in my version of `opencv` using the following:

`cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE`

What is strange, is that in my function which actually captures the photograph, I can see that the default exposure value is 0.0, and then when I go to change it with the set method, the exposure hasn't changed when I check the value again. It would appear that the set method is simply not working.

Here is my function:

```
def takePhoto():
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    print(cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE)) #this prints out 0.0
    cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE, 0.5)
    print(cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE)) #this also prints out 0.0, despite the use of set() in the line above
    s, im = cam.read() # captures image
    cv2.imwrite("test.jpg",im) # writes image test.jpg to disk
    cam.release()
```

Is it just the case that this camera is not compatible with manual exposure control? I have also read in one or two places that `opencv` in OSX does not allow for manually controlling properties of cameras. Is that what's wrong here? Or am I using the set method improperly? I just really need to be able to manually control exposure, as the photos taken by my program are consistently underexposed.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a FacetimeHD Camera but I guess  you need to set the exposure mode to manual (disable auto exposure) using

`cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_AUTO_EXPOSURE, 0)`

Comment: IMHO values may differ from camera to camera.